# AppHarbor's IIS logs

Tags: appharbor, iis-logs

Is there a way to get the IIS logs for a website hosted on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/)? I have one site hosted on it and I am getting run time exception. Currently I get a suggestion that I should enable custom errors to view the exception. I don't want to do this since it is a deployed instance which is being used by users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS logs are not currently available but you can [access unhandled exceptions in the error interface](http://blog.appharbor.com/2011/03/28/application-errors) on AppHarbor.

You can also use something like [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) (appropriately locked down) to record and inspect errors.

We're working on making HTTP access logs available too.

Comment: This is currently the first result on Google for this search.  Do you have an update?

Comment: We'll soon expose load balancer logs (and a bunch of other logging sources) which will contain similar data. IIS logs may be added later if it adds value. Exceptions are still accessible through the an application's error page as friism mentioned in the original answer.

Comment: Request logs are now available - more information in the announcement blog post here http://blog.appharbor.com/2013/07/01/introducing-realtime-logging